# What is the purpose of the Reader Monad's local function?

Tags: javascript

Simply put, the Reader Monad is just a wrapper around a function. It is good for implicitly passing configuration info through a computation:

```js
const ap = f => x => f(x);
const id = x => x;
const co = x => y => x;
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const Reader = ap(cons => f => {
  const t = new cons();
  t.run = x => f(x);
  return t;
}) (function Reader() {});

Reader.map = f => tf => Reader(comp(f) (tf.run));
Reader.ap = af => ag => Reader(x => af.run(x) (ag.run(x)));
Reader.chain = mf => fm => Reader(x => fm(mf.run(x)).run(x));
Reader.of = f => Reader(co(f));
Reader.ask = () => Reader(id);
Reader.asks = f => Reader.chain(Reader.ask) (x => Reader.of(f(x)));
Reader.local = f => tf => Reader(comp(tf.run) (f));

const compM = tDict => fm => gm => x =>
  tDict.chain(tDict.chain(tDict.of(x)) (gm)) (fm);

const foo = n => Reader(env => (console.log(env), n + 1)),
  c = compM(Reader) (foo) (foo) (2);

console.log(
  c.run("shared environment")
);
```

However, I couldn't find a good example for `local` and I lack imagination how to use it. I understand that `local` is just `contramap` but that doesn't help much. So what is its purpose?

Comment: Where did you find this code? Please link it source. (It doesn't sound like you did write it yourself if you have trouble understanding it)

Comment: I'm forcing myself to learn about Reader monad now such that maybe I can contribute to this conversation... ^_^

Comment: @Bergi Actually I wrote it myself, mostly based on Haskell type signatures. The monad pattern is recurring and reproducing it for a particular monad is often not that hard. However, I frequently find it difficult to apply this patterns or to recognize appropiate use cases.

Comment: Did you see the [mtl example for `local`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#g:5)?

Comment: @Bergi No, I didn't. I try to translate it and post it as an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that `local` is just `contramap` but that doesn't help much. So what is its purpose?

Well `contramap` is just as important as `map` – in [the example Bergi linked](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#g:5) (translated here into JS), `local` allows to affect the value *before* the next reader gets it

```
const calculateLength =
  Reader.map (s => s.length) (Reader.ask ())

const calculateModifiedLength = 
  Reader.local (s => 'Prefix ' + s) (calculateLength)

console.log (calculateLength.run ('12345'))
// '12345'.length == 5
// => 5    

console.log (calculateModifiedLength.run ('12345'))
// 'Prefix 12345'.length == 12
// => 12
```

Here's your Reader monad, lovingly reformatted. I included a demo of each function so that we can verify each result is correct. Thanks for making me finally learn about this interesting monad!

```js
const Reader = f =>
  ({ run : x => f (x) })

Reader.of = x =>
  Reader (() => x)

Reader.chain = f => m =>
  Reader (x => f (m.run (x)) .run (x))
  
Reader.map = f => m =>
  Reader (x => f (m.run (x)))

Reader.ap = f => m =>
  Reader (x => f.run (x) (m.run (x)))
  
Reader.join = m =>
  Reader (x => m.run (x) .run (x))

Reader.ask = () =>
  Reader (identity)
  
Reader.local = f => m =>
  Reader (x => m.run (f (x)))

const identity = x => x
const sq = x => x * x
const add = x => y => x + y

const calculateLength =
  Reader.map (s => s.length) (Reader.ask ())

const calculateModifiedLength = 
  Reader.local (s => 'Prefix ' + s) (calculateLength)
  
console.log
  ( Reader.chain (x => Reader.of (x + 1)) (Reader (sq)) .run (4) // 17    sq (4) + 1
  , Reader.chain (x => Reader (add (x))) (Reader (sq)) .run (4)  // 20    sq (4) + 4
  , Reader.map (sq) (Reader (sq)) .run (4)                       // 256   sq (sq (4))
  , Reader.ap (Reader.of (sq)) (Reader.of (4)) .run ()           // 16    sq (4)
  , Reader.ap (Reader (add)) (Reader (sq)) .run (4)              // 20   sq (4) + 4 
  , Reader.join (Reader.of (Reader.of (4))) .run ()              // 4
  , Reader.ask () .run (4)                                       // 4
  , calculateLength .run ('12345')                               // 5    '12345'.length
  , calculateModifiedLength .run ('12345')                       // 12   'Prefix 12345'.length
  )
```

And here's the type signatures, for those that are interested

```
Reader :: (e -> a) -> Reader e a
Reader.of :: a -> Reader e a 
Reader.chain :: (a -> Reader e b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b
Reader.map :: (a -> b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b  
Reader.ap :: Reader e (a -> b) -> Reader e a -> Reader e b
Reader.join :: Reader e (Reader e a) -> Reader e a   
Reader.ask :: () -> Reader a a
Reader.local :: (e -> e) -> Reader e a -> Reader e a
```

Comment: Oh, you did the work I was supposed to do...thank you! I suspected that `local` would contain more "magic". But it's just `contramap`.

Comment: Wouldn't the signature of `local` be `Reader.local :: (f -> e) -> Reader e a -> Reader f a`, since it is just `contramap`? sure the signature you gave holds when `f ~ e`, but why restrict yourself to only that case?

Comment: @M.Aroosi My last comment was inaccurate. When you map the general monad type `m a` to its `Reader` instance `Reader e a` then `m` corresponds to `Reader e` and `a` to `a`. Now it is clear that you must not change `e`s type, because `e` is part of the context to be preserved. Anyway, I am not trying to lecture you on this. It's rather for future readers...

Comment: @ftor `Monad` doesn't contain a definition for `local`. `local` is something particular to `Reader`(or if we look at Haskell's mtl library, to the `MonadReader` type class, in which case your argument holds). But this is a Javascript question and Javascript doesn't have type classes or even interfaces(natively). Based on the code given the type would be as I wrote. if you wish to restrict the use (by convention or some other tool) to only the case were `f~e`, But that's like saying the type of Haskell's prelude `id` is `Monad a => a -> a` because you only ever use it that way. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @M.Aroosi I am totally fine with your type, but use a distinct name, so that people don't expect certain behavior.